# Keep all content to one section of a multi-row layout

Tags: php, web

I have a web application whose loading page presents a form with radioboxes for 3 types of input : Color, Size, Material. This loading page is basically a php file *first.php* that has 3 sections, a Header div, a Content div which presents the form and a footer div.

The action target for the Submit button is a 2nd file *process.php* which offers a page of choices. I want this file to exactly take up the space occupied by *first.php* - which is to say, I want the header and footer to stay as they are throughout the life of the
session. I *could* load the header and footer for every target php file but I'd rather save on the amount of content from server to browser.

What should I do to ensure that the 2nd(and every subsequent nth page) stays only in the content sub-section? The code for *first.php* is like this:
    
    header comes here

```
<div id="content">
<form action="process.php" method="post">
.....
</form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
footer comes here
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is the method implemented by me: maybe not the best one, but the one giving me the best results without too many hassles.

1. make a framework page with all the HTML and some "holes" for the generated text, e.g. `$header`, `$article`, `$footer` and everything you have to change;
2. instead of a plain `echo` save the output into the variables above;
3. for every page include the framework as last line: `include_once ('framework.inc');` and the "holes" will be filled.

BTW, I use also other variables for the CSS and Javascript specific to a certain page, for the `<title>` and other variable parts.

All the common php functions (session manipulation, DB management, etc.) are placed into another file, general.inc, included at the beginning of the page with `include_once ('general.inc');`.

If you want to hide those include files on your web server have their name starting with `.ht`, and Apache will not serve them.

Answer (score 0):

I have read recently about dynamic loading content to just selected section by using JQuery Mobile lib: https://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load

Please check out engine descibed f.e. here: http://blog.stikki.me/2011/08/18/loading-dynamic-content-in-jquery-mobile-with-jquerys-load-function/
and of course remember about naming convention of jquery mobile sections.

IMHO it works quite good (;